# k-nearest neighbors algorithm classes count

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, classification, nearest-neighbor

This is just a newbie question. KNN is able to do the classification of each point in the entry set based on the distance, but how the algorithm knows how much classes is in the dataset? Does it generate automatically this count of classes, or is it an input variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it generate automatically this count of classes, or is it an input variable?

It's an **input** variable.

Comment: what if i don't know the count of classes

Comment: Then KNN classification won't work out for you @luky. Moreover, that's a different question. Open set recognition for example *may* do the trick for you...Hope that helps!

Comment: aha, now i see it works probably that the KNN takes some dataset where the classes of vectors are known, and it should be able to classify any new future value based on the starting data, am i right.

Comment: Yeah @luky you first train, and then you test! ;)